# C - lenght of Array of Strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have my array of strings -> `*nome[] = {"String1","String2","String3"}`

Now, I want iterate all my strings.

I have tried doing

```
while(nome[i] != '\0')
```

but I have always the same problem - Segmentation Fault

Comment: change to `*nome[] = {"String1","String2","String3", NULL}`

Comment: And the loop to `while (nome[i] != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use container ,such as vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> svec;
    /*append some elements*/
    svec.push_back("string1");
    svec.push_back("string2");
    svec.push_back("string3");

    for(vector<string>::iterator it = svec.begin();
            it != svec.end(); ++it)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Using iterator, you don't need to know where the array is overflow and segmentation fault may not occur.I hope that can help you !!